# Setting QPixmap to Qlabel gives segmentation fault and app crashes

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qlabel, qimage, qpixmap

```
GstFlowReturn MainWindow::newSample1(GstAppSink *sink1, gpointer gSelf)
{
    GstSample* sample = NULL;
    GstBuffer* sampleBuffer = NULL;
    GstMapInfo bufferInfo;
    MainWindow* self = static_cast<MainWindow* >(gSelf);
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(sink1));
    QImage image ;
    QPixmap image1 ;
    if(sample != NULL)
    {
        sampleBuffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
        if(sampleBuffer != NULL)
        {
            gst_buffer_map(sampleBuffer, &bufferInfo, GST_MAP_READ);
            image = QImage(bufferInfo.data, 640, 480, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
            image1 = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

             if(!image1.isNull())
             { 
self->ui->CAM_VDO->setPixmap(image1);       
             }           
            gst_buffer_unmap(sampleBuffer, &bufferInfo);

        }

        gst_sample_unref(sample);
    }

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

This application runs for 1 or 2 seconds shows images too but then crashes, gives segmentation fault error.

But when i remove or comment this line :

self->ui->CAM_VDO->setPixmap(image1);

it runs fine.
So i think there is something wrong with Qlabel or am i missing something else.

"CAM_VDO" is a QLabel.

Comment: Probably the caller of this function calls it with a dangling pointer `gSelf`.

Comment: As a diagnostic, try using  `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. Do you get a non-zero result in `self`?

Comment: @TonyK, `dynamic_cast` will not help to identify dangling pointers. Unfortunately.

Comment: @vahancho: don't you think it's worth trying anyway? It doesn't take long.

Comment: @TonyK, we may try everything, but why should we try something that doesn't work by definitions? By the way, calling `dynamic_cast` on a dangling pointer is undefined behavior, and proposing it even dangerous.

Comment: @vahancho what should i do, someone suggested to use QMetaObject::invokeMethod and then update the UI but i have no idea how to use it.Can you please help